# unnested Redshift json array issue. Partiql syntax

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a query that looks like this:

```
with first as (SELECT JSON_PARSE(
                              CASE
                                  WHEN REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'works', 'string'), '\\"',
                                               '"') = '' THEN '[]'
                                  ELSE REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'works', 'string'), '\\"',
                                               '"')
                                  END
                          ) as works_formatted
               FROM <table>
)
select f.*, wf."id" from first AS f, f.works_formatted AS
```

and first is a SUPER type that looks like this:

```
[{"id":"Education setting","selected":true,"displayName":"Education setting"}, {"id":"Education setting2","selected":true,"displayName":"Education setting2"}]
```

but when I try to run the query above...  Iget this error:

```
[XX000] ERROR: Unnest subquery's result on leader is not supported
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I array unnested the SUPER type?

***EDIT***

turns out, it can't be a CTE but it does work as a materialized table. Why is this?

```
create table partitest as (SELECT JSON_PARSE(
                              CASE
                                  WHEN REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'works', 'string'), '\\"',
                                               '"') = '' THEN '[]'
                                  ELSE REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'works', 'string'), '\\"',
                                               '"')
                                  END
                          ) as works_formatted
               FROM <table>
)
```

and then this works:

```
select p.*, wf."id" from partitest as p, p.works_formatted as wf
```

Why is this?